# Login in Wordpress and use this logged user in Symfony

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, session, session-cookies

I have a page developed in Wordpress and to enter to this page you have to register and then login into the same.
Now I have to develop another system and I have to use the same session in my new page that was logged in Wordpress.
In the Wordpress page there is a link that brings to Symfony 2 page. Clicking in that link, the user must be the same.
I am using the same database for both applications, so the *wp_users* table from Wordpress is used by the new Symfony2 page.
For example the user logged in Wordpress page has to fill certain form developed in the new Symfony2 page.
[image: Basic Flow]
I found this [bundle](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoWordpressBundle) but I don't know how to use it. It seems very useful.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to save the session in a cookie and use this cookie in my Symfony2 app?
- Is there a way to send a token in the link in the Wordpress page and use this token in my Symfony2 page? This token should contains the user logged info.

Comment: I think you won't find many people here that would have experience with such thing. I think you are pretty lucky there is that bundle that you linked, which does should do exactly what you want. I'm nost sure what you mean by "I don't know how to use it", you need to give us more detailed problem.

Comment: Hi @Miro: I wanted to say "how works this bundle". I don't know how to get the user session in Wordpress with this bundle. Thanks.

Comment: in wordpress you get user with `wp_get_current_user()` : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

Comment: Hi, I have a similar situation. Did you find a good solution for this problem?

Comment: HI @klodoma 
Finally I did not use this solution for this situation.
I left the session in WordPress and made a restful application with Spring Boot to manage the transactions. The security in my case was not much important so took that decision in that moment. 
I sent the user id, rol and password in all the requests to restful and this spring boot application only can access locally from Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, what you are asking for is possible but is some pretty technical stuff. Your best bet is to try and follow the instructions for the bundle you linked to get the user auth working. Baring that if you wanted to roll your own solution, assuming you are on symfony 2.8 or later you would need to implement a custom user provider and a guard.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html

Basically the idea would be to read the session cookie created by wordpress, use doctrine to look up that session again in wordpress db, get the user ID associated with that. Use that User ID to load the custom user entity you created for the custom user provider.

Someone providing that solution on here likely wont happen with just how much effort would be involved.